# Level system in a type speed test program

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem includes a textbox which you are meant to read to type out in the input box, this then determines the speed of your typing. I tried to call different variables which depend on the button however anything I try doesn't work. I am using tkinter with a gui

My code looks like this

```
import tkinter as tk 
import time 
import threading 
import random 

global levelsel # level select 

class TypeSpeedGUI: 
    
    def __init__(self):
         
        self.root =tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Type Speed App")  # Title
        self.root.geometry("800x600")

        global levelsel # level select 
        levelsel = 0
        self.texty = open("start.txt", "r").read().split("\n") 

        if levelsel == "1":
            self.texty = open("texts1.txt", "r").read().split("\n") 
        elif levelsel == "1":
            self.texty = open("texts2.txt", "r").read().split("\n")        
        elif levelsel == "1":
            self.texty = open("texts3.txt", "r").read().split("\n") 
        else: 
            self.texty = open("start.txt", "r").read().split("\n") 

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)

        self.sample_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=random.choice(self.texty), font =("Helvetica", 18)) # Text 
        self.sample_label.grid(row=1, column = 3, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.input_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=40, font=("Helvetica", 24))
        self.input_entry.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.input_entry.bind("<KeyPress>", self.start)

        self.speed_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text ="Speed: \n0.00 CPS\n0.00 CPM\n0.00 WPM\n0.00 WPS", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        self.speed_label.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        
        self.reset_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Reset", command=self.reset)
        self.reset_button.grid(row=5, column=3, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.level1_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Level 1", command=self.level1)
        self.level1_button.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.level2_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Level 2", command=self.level2)
        self.level2_button.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.level3_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Level 3", command=self.level3)
        self.level3_button.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.frame.pack(expand=True)

        self.counter = 0 
        self.started = False

        self.root.mainloop()

    def start(self, event):
        if not self.started: 
            if not event.keycode in [16, 17, 18]: 
                self.started = True 
                t = threading.Thread(target=self.time_thread)
                t.start()
        if not self.sample_label.cget("text").startswith(self.input_entry.get()):
            self.input_entry.config(fg="red")
        else:
            self.input_entry.config(fg="black")
        if self.input_entry.get() == self.sample_label.cget("text")[:-1]:
            self.started = False 
            self.input_entry.config(fg="green")
                        

    def time_thread(self):
        while self.started:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.counter += 0.1 
            cps = len(self.input_entry.get()) / self.counter
            cpm = cps * 60
            wps = len(self.input_entry.get().split(" ")) / self.counter
            wpm = wps * 60
            self.speed_label.config(text=f"Speed: \n{cps:.2f} CPS\n{cpm:.2f} CPM\n{wps:.2f} WPS\n{wpm:.2f} WPM")

    def level1():
        levelsel = "1"
        
    
    def level2(self):
        levelsel = "2"
        

    def level3(self):
        levelsel = "3"
        

    def reset(self):
        self.sample_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=random.choice(self.texty), font =("Helvetica", 18))
        self.started = False 
        self.counter = 0 
        self.speed_label.config(text="Speed: \n0.00 CPS\n0.00 CPM\n0.00 WPM\n0.00 WPS")
        self.sample_label.config(text=random.choice(self.texty))
        self.input_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    
    

TypeSpeedGUI()
```

[image: This is my root folder]

[image: My program running(doesn't work)]

I have tried calling a global variable to change what file is being opened depending on the value however it does not work.

Comment: inside `def level1()` and `def level2()` and `def level3()` you have to use `global levelsel`. OR better: use `self.levelsel` in all code.

Comment: you forgot `self` in `def level1(self):`

Comment: what means `doesn't work`? Do you get error message? Did you run code in console/terminal to see error message? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't like to use widgets in `threads`. Maybe you should use `root.after(millisecond, function_name)` to create loop without using `while True` and thread. `after()` doesn't block `tkinter`

Comment: if you want to see different file when you click button then you should use `self.texty = open(...).read()` in `def level1()` and `def level2()` and `def level3()`